# Hide the header ( link) of accordian from the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a form which consist of three parts. I want to shift to other form via clicking 'next' button rather than clicking header portion of jquery. i had implemented jquery accordion in the form and shifting to other via next and back button. But i cant hide the link  or header of accordion. I want to hide that link(header of accordion)
Thanks in advance

```
<h1 class="top bottom"><span>Help me</span> Buy and Sell a House</h1>
<h2>This form is quick &amp; easy to complete - in only 3 steps!</h2>

<form name="cmaForm" id="cmaForm" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="recordRequestPrimaryServiceID" id="recordRequestPrimaryServiceID" value="100" />
    <input type="hidden" name="recordClientServices" id="recordClientServices" value="1,3" />

    <ul id="stepForm" class="ui-accordion-container">
    <li id="sf1">
        <a href='#' class="ui-accordion-link"> </a>
        <div>
            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <input name="formNext1" type="button" class="open1 nextbutton" value="Next" alt="Next" title="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="sf2">
        <a href='#' class="ui-accordion-link"></a>
        <div>
            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <input name="formBack0" type="button" class="open0 prevbutton" value="Back" alt="Back" title="Back" />
                <input name="formNext2" type="button" class="open2 nextbutton" value="Next" alt="Next" title="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="sf3">
        <a href='#' class="ui-accordion-link"></a>
        <div>
            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <input name="formBack1" type="button" class="open1 prevbutton" value="Back" alt="Back" title="Back" />
                <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton" alt="Submit" title="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</form>
```

And in javascript i code on the event of button click to switch between different form

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //display the form in the accordion
            var accordion = $('#stepForm').accordion();
            var current = 0;

            $('.open1').on('click',function(){
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", 1);
                current = 1;
            });

            $('.open2').on('click',function(){
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", 2);
                current = 2;
            });

            $('.open3').on('click',function(){
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", 3);
                current = 3;
            });

            $('#sf3 .prevbutton').on('click', function(){
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", 1);
                current = 1;
            });

            $('#sf2 .prevbutton').on('click', function(){
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", 0);
                current = 0;
            });
 });
    </script>
```

But now user can switch between various form by clicking header also. I want to disable or hide( would be best) that functionality.

Comment: Can you provide some code? jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please provide some code and create a js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable event for the accordian. Your button clicking code will still work.

`accordion.accordion({event: false});`

I've also added in this line so that the headers don't look like links when you hover. You can modify the css for this though

`$('.ui-accordion-header').css('cursor', 'default');`

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9PbM/